# loopj library gives connection refused error on slow internet

Tags: android, youtube-api

I am developing an app in which i am getting the data from Youtube using youtube api, every thing is working fine on healthy internet, but i get connection refused error on slow internet. how to fix this ? replace library or any other option ?

Comment: Slow internet can be the problem, I am using the same, I didn't found any issue. Can you share the specific code you are using to get the data.

Comment: I have an other app in which i am not using loopj library, in that app i am simply getting data using AsyncTask doInBackground(), that is working fine on slow internet also. But now  i wana use some library to handle the network calls, so i used loopj and now problem is i am getting connection refused error on slow internet and working fine on healthy internet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you mentioned that you are using **loopj**

Yes, this is the right way to call any service through any **Asynchronous libraries**, **loopj** is very nice library but I faced the same issues of getting slow data on complex JSONS Structure. 
I searched alot, everyone said that slow internet is the main issue. I studied android documentation, there I found **VOLLEY** which is [recommended by android](http://developer.android.com/training/volley/index.html), just study the Volley documentation and you will see the difference. I **didn't found any issue** after using VOLLEY.

Comment: I'll give this a try. Ty for the ans.